# Xquery to find the next to last item

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

with xml something like:

```
<item > 
   <datapoint>5</datapoint>
</item>
<item > 
   <datapoint>4</datapoint>
</item>
<item > 
   <datapoint>6</datapoint>
</item>
<item > 
   <datapoint>8</datapoint>
</item>
<item > 
   <datapoint>9</datapoint>
</item>
```

And the number of items is not a fixed number.  I am already retrieving the last() data point, however I now also need to grab the next to last data point. So in this example I need to separately return both the 8 and the 9.

Comment: While asking an XQuery question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**: 
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XQuery that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XQuery processor and its conformance with the XQuery standards: 1.0, 3.0, or 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XQuery should work:

```
for $it in $file/item[position()=last() or position()=last()-1]
return $it/datapoint
```

Or, you could also use a shorter version:

```
for $it in $file/item[position()>=last()-1]
return $it/datapoint
```

Output is:

```
<datapoint>8</datapoint>
<datapoint>9</datapoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your XML should be well-formed. That's why I added a root element

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item>
        <datapoint>5</datapoint>
    </item>
    <item>
        <datapoint>4</datapoint>
    </item>
    <item>
        <datapoint>6</datapoint>
    </item>
    <item>
        <datapoint>8</datapoint>
    </item>
    <item>
        <datapoint>9</datapoint>
    </item>
</root>
```

**XQuery**

```
for $x in /root/item[last()-1]/datapoint
return $x
```

**Output**

```
<datapoint>8</datapoint>
```